# How to put a string variable in between URL in between URl in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I actually obtained a string with session.getAttribute and stored it in a variable named uname. Now I want to use this variable in between a hyperlink such that the name of the username who logged in appears as a hyperlink. I have tried the following, but it is showing error. Thanks in advance for the help.

<%String uname=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");%>

<%=uname%>'s Account

<%=uname%>'s Account is the error in this. Not understanding, How I can display the user's name here.

Comment: What error is it displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **NOT** use scriptlets.

You can use JSP Expression Language.

```
<--There is bean in some scope with the key 'uname' -->
<a href="/xyz">${uname}</a>

<--There is bean in some scope with the key 'user' 
   and it is an instance of a class which has a method getUserName() -->
<a href="/xyz">${user.userName}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Well, I just want the logic behind it. Does ${uname} mean that we referring to a bean?

Comment: You are referring to an object that has been added to, for example,  the request or session using:
request.setAttribute("uname", someObject) or request.getSession().setAttribute("uname", someObject).